# Laravel Queue - My aync Queue doesn't trigger email while the synchronous one does

Tags: laravel, dom, queue, domdocument

When I put QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync in my .env file I can fire the email without any problems anymore when I switch to "database" scheduling the job and then run the queue:work command my work fails and returns:

```
ErrorException: Undefined property: DOMDocument::$documentElement in /home/admin/web/api.lojadodia.com/public_html/seunegocio.pt/vendor/tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles/src/CssToInlineStyles.php:132
Stack trace:
#0 /home/admin/web/api.lojadodia.com/public_html/seunegocio.pt/vendor/tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles/src/CssToInlineStyles.php(132): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Undefined prope...', '/home/admin/web...', 132)
#1 /home/admin/web/api.lojadodia.com/public_html/seunegocio.pt/vendor/tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles/src/CssToInlineStyles.php(50): TijsVerkoyen\CssToInlineStyles\CssToInlineStyles->getHtmlFromDocument(Object(DOMDocument))
#2 /home/admin/web/api.lojadodia.com/public_html/seunegocio.pt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Markdown.php(75): TijsVerkoyen\CssToInlineStyles\CssToInlineStyles->convert('<!DOCTYPE html ...', '/* Base */\n\nbod...')
#3 /home/admin/web/api.lojadodia.com/public_html/seunegocio.pt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Channels/MailChannel.php(101): Illuminate\Mail\Markdown->render('emails.order.pl...', Array)
#4 /home/admin/web/api.lojadodia.com/public_html/seunegocio.pt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Channels/MailChannel.php(63): Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\MailChannel->buildView(Object(Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage))
#5 /home/admin/web/api.lojadodia.com/public_html/seunegocio.pt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/NotificationSender.php(148): Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\MailChannel->send(Object(PickBazar\Database\Models\User), Object(PickBazar\Notifications\OrderPlacedSuccessfully))
```

Comment: which laravel version you are using ?

Comment: As per my understanding, you are using some styling package. which cause error.
1st send plain job/email. for this you will get exact picture of error

Comment: @elvis-marçal what was the solution for this?